# Copy last commits from master to branch

Tags: git

Present situation in the picture. Green branch is a master. How to copy last 3 commits from master to pink branch, but without touching a master ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean you wished you had waited to branch (and it's a personal project branch) you can (from branch "pink") use `git rebase master`.  That will pop off the pink commits, move `pink` ahead to 29934b6 and then re-apply the patches.

Otherwise Amber's `git merge` is probably the best answer.

Another possibility is (again, from "pink") `git cherry-pick 9a51fd2; ...` for each of those changes.  That will make individual new commits on pink.  You can also name the branches as `master`, `master^` and `master^^`.

Answer (score 13):

```
git checkout <name of pink branch>
git merge master
```

will do exactly what you want (merge the 3 commits from `master` into the pink branch, but leave `master` itself where it is).

Comment: Note that it will lead to non-linear history, which is not necessarily good. Other options are either to use `cherry-pick`, or, more properly, to `rebase` pink branch to master.

Comment: Non-linear history is fine; Git is designed to work with history that is inherently non-linear. Rebasing tends to cause more problems than it solves for people who don't have a strong understanding of Git internals.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh: What's wrong with non-linear history? It accurately represents the changes as they were made.

Comment: I did not said that non-linear history is bad for all cases. However, it has its tradeoffs, just like rebasing. A proper answer, IMO, would list all options, and allow OP to pick one that he needs, based on his workflow.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Personally, I disagree. There is no need to introduce more complex history rewriting tools when the simplest answer (conceptually and practically) is sufficient. Non-linear history is a fact of development. Recording an artificially linear history is only sometimes useful or necessary.

Comment: Especially since there is no external context about whether the other branch in question is a shared branch, et cetera - rebase could cause significant other problems in some situations, whereas merge is completely safe.